# Submit the data attribute of selected option instead of value in HTML form

Tags: javascript, forms

On pressing submit, I would like to submit the data-item attribute instead of value.

```
<option value={{n.value}} data-item={i[0]}>{{ i[1] }}</option>
```

Comment: Will this not work value={i[0]} ?

Comment: @TusharShahi  That would work but I need the other variable in value for something else.

Comment: You will have to show your form submission code then. There you will have to manipulate the value before saving.